# Simple python script to read GPX files+optparse

Tags: python, optparse, gpx

I'm new to python and trying to write a simple script to extract particular information from a GPX file. The limiting problem in my script below is that it can't seem to find the dtime in the else statement, but can see it in the first if statement. Perhaps my newness to python is escaping me, as I'm pretty sure there is an easy solution for this. Can anyone tell me how to get it to see the variable dtime or what I'm doing wrong?

Furthermore is there a better way to have it use the flags. The -D and -P will never have input by the user but the intention was to have the GPX file be read when those two flags were defined.

Here's the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pnpython3

import gpxpy.parser
import os
def get_args () :
    ''' Parse input args
            -x   gpx filename
            -d   default deploy time yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss
            -p   default pickup time yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss
            -D   read deploy time from GPX file
            -P   read pickup time from GPX file
            -l   line number (array)
    '''
    global GPX, DEPLOY, PICKUP, LINE

    from optparse import OptionParser

    oparser = OptionParser ()
    oparser.usage = "munge_wp.py -x gps_file_name -d deploy_yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss -ppickup_yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss -l line_number"
    oparser.description = "Read a GPX way point file and produce a CSV file."
    oparser.add_option ("-x", "--gpx", dest = "gpx_file",help = "GPX input file",metavar = "gpx_file")
    oparser.add_option ("-d", "--deploy", dest = "deploy_time",help="Deploy time yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss",metavar = "deploy_time")
    oparser.add_option ("-p", "--pickup", dest = "pickup_time",
                    help="Pickup time yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss",
                    metavar = "pickup_time")
    oparser.add_option ("-D", "--Deploy", dest = "D_time",help="D_time will be read from GPX file and put in the following format yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss",metavar = "D_time")
    oparser.add_option ("-P", dest = "P_time", help="P_time will be read from GPX file and put 
                    in the following format yyyy:jjj:hh:mm:ss.sss",
                    metavar = "P_time")
    oparser.add_option ("-l", "--line", dest = "line_number",help = "The line number. Caution: Assumes that all stations in GPX file are on same line",metavar = "line_number")

    options, args = oparser.parse_args()
    #print options.outfile

    GPX = options.gpx_file
    DEPLOY = options.deploy_time
    PICKUP = options.pickup_time
    LINE = options.line_number
    DTIME = options.D_time
    PTIME = options.P_time


def open_gpx () :
    fh = open (GPX)
    gpx_parser = gpxpy.parser.GPXParser (fh)
    gpx_parser.parse ()
    fh.close ()
    return gpx_parser.get_gpx ()
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    get_args ()
    gpx = open_gpx ()
    print "#STA\tDAS\tLAT\tLON\tELEV\tDEPLOY\tPICKUP\tLINE"
    for wp in gpx.waypoints :
        s=wp.name
        staname = s.split('-')[0]
        #print staname
        das = s.split('-')[1]
        #print das
        t=wp.time
        dtme=os.popen("date -d t +%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
        dtime=dtme.read()
        if "DEPLOY"  in locals() or "PICKUP" in locals():
                                                         line = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}".format (staname,
                                                                                                                     das,
                                                                                                                     wp.latitude,
                                                                                                                     wp.longitude,
                                                                                                                     wp.elevation,
                                                                                                                     DEPLOY,
                                                                                                                     PICKUP,
                                                                                                                     LINE)
                                                   print line
        else:
            line = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}".format (staname,
                                                                das,
                                                                wp.latitude,
                                                                wp.longitude,
                                                                wp.elevation,
                                                                dtime,
                                                                dtime,
                                                                LINE)
            print line
```

Comment: can you try fix you indentation. That may be half the battle.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `optparse` in a new project? As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html) say, it's been deprecated since 2.7/3.2: "The `optparse` module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the `argparse` module." And `argparse` is easier to debug.

Comment: Also, what exactly is happening that's wrong? Is it exiting with an exception? If so, paste the exception with traceback. Is it giving the wrong output? If so, post the expected and actual output. Just giving us a guess about what might be causing the error without telling us what the error is makes things very difficult.

Comment: I'm using 2.6.6 because I'm on an old server at the moment, so I switched back to optparse

Comment: The indentation is not like that in my script. I will try to edit it in the window

Comment: @user1332577: As posted, the `if` comes after the `for` loop is finished, instead of once for each iteration of the loop, which means the only `dtime` you're ever going to see is the very last one… but the same is true for all of the other values, so I suspect that isn't the problem in your real code?

Comment: I fixed the indentation

Comment: why do you have `dtime` twice in your else statement?

Comment: @abarnert how would I change it to make it look at it for every iteration...

Comment: indent the `if` and `else` inside the loop

Comment: @padraic, the second one is a space holder for now, until I add a ptime, but was trying to deal with the larger issue of not seeing it for the moment

Comment: you are only seeing the final value when you reach the end of your loop, you need the `if` and `else` `inside` your `loop`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on the copy on my part. The if and else are indented in the for loop. I've fixed it. How come I can't see dtime though?

Comment: You will only see it if the `if` condition is `False`, have you printed inside the loop to see if your condition is actually False any time?

Comment: So maybe my if condition will always be true. What I'm trying to say is if the user uses the -d or -p flag put in the DEPLOY and PICKUP, but if they use the -D or -P flag put in the dtime. Really would be great if they use -D and -P, so if both conditions are met. Same for -d and -p. What would that look like. I guess i'm struggling in my knowledge of python on how those are being stored in python

Comment: have you tried this to see what happens? Put some prints in to check the values you expect, it is the easiest way to find a bug

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. My if statement was wonky and would be true no matter what. Thanks everyone who responded. Sometimes just talking it out with people helps.

Comment: no worries,  print is your friend when debugging!